# Need a hand in Windows batch processing syntax

Tags: loops, execution, batch-processing

I have compiled a C++ program on Windows, and I need it to process a huge number of my data files. The files are named, for instance, "x0000y" to "x9999y".

The C++ program only takes one file at a time, create the output of each respective file, save somewhere, and terminate. I do not want to hard code the program, as my data set does not always have the same number of files - and keep recompiling the program just for this is not cool. So I am looking for a quick way of doing this: batch processing.

Here comes the trouble: I am having trouble trying to get the batch syntax correct and valid. So could somebody show me the following pseudocode in **batch processing version**?:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lastFile; i++){

    String filename;

    /*
    Because the files are named "x0000y", "x0034y", etc. 
    We need to put in all the extra 0s in the string if i is less than 1000.
    */
    String numberedString = convertNumToFourDigit(i);

    filename = "myFileName" + numberedString + "Footer";       

    /*
    execute the program with the respective filename.
    */
    execute("MyProgram.exe " + filename);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you'll need in your .bat file to run your program against all of the files in the current directory.

```
for %%I IN (*) DO ( MyProgram.exe %%I )
```

If the data files are in a subdirectory with an extension, here's an example.

```
for %%I IN (subdir\*.dat) DO ( MyProgram.exe %%I )
```

If you only want files in the form of x0000y, then this will do the trick.

```
for %%I IN (x????y) DO ( MyProgram.exe %%I )
```

These will process the data files in whatever order the filesystem provides their names.

Comment: Actually, I want the program to process only the file "x0000y" to "x9999y", not all the files in the directory.

Comment: I added a third to filter only those files for you.  Each question mark represents a single unknown character.  You could also replace all four of them with a single asterix.